# innerHTML property does not fill container with content

Tags: javascript

so I'm trying to build html block and append it to container which was created before. Somehow its working on other pages but struggles to display data on the current one.

```js
this.node = document.querySelector('.primary_block');
this.element = document.createElement('div');
this.element.className = 'slides_pageName';
this.element.style.cssText = 'position: relative;';

this.body = '<div><div>text ';
this.element.innerHTML = this.body + buildRecommendationsBody() + '</div></div>';
this.node.parentNode.insertBefore(this.element, this.node.nextSibling);

function buildRecommendationsBody(){
  return 'magic content';
}
```

```html
<div id="body">
  <div class="primary_block">primary block</div>
  <div class="block_last">last block</div>
</div>
```

after running the code I can see that the element `.slides_pagename` was created and the css rule `position: relative;` was applied successfully. I can even print `this.element.innerHTML` and see that it contains all data I need. **BUT** somehow `this.node.parentNode.insertBefore` adds only empty container without `innerHTML` that was created. How is it even possible and how to handle the situation?

**EDIT** using snippet it works with random content but does not work with my content which is being applied.

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)).

Answer (score -1):

What are you trying to solve with this?

If you want to add html you need to assign valid HTML string to `.innerHTML` method.

Here you are closing some div element which have not been opened previously

`this.buildRecommendationsBody(data) + '</div></div>';`

Comment: its valid since `this.body` which was created before has 2 open divs which needs to be closed after appending created content.